# spring cloud zuul: Active-Active configuration

Tags: netflix-zuul

1.) How to configure Zuul to redirect the request to another Zuul instances in the other cloud region when there is a service cluster failover?.

2.) How to configure Zuul to accept https request & forward request as https to the service cluster.

3.) Is there a document that explains what are the different configuration options that can used to configure the Zuul server using yml.